# Get <input> value with jQuery and calculate with this value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't solve my problem. I would like to get a number from input box  with button click, and alert the result, but always get 0 value. Thanks for help!

Here is my code which called on button click:

```
function szamolo(){

    var sqmeter = $("#new").val();

    //#new is my input box id

    var eredmeny = ((sqmeter *0.8)/1.65);

    alert(eredmeny);

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to parse your value from a String to a Number with : `var sqmeter = +$("#new").val();` or `var sqmeter = parseInt($("#new").val());`

Comment: Try add type input to `number` or convert input value to `int`

Comment: This should generally work as far as I can tell (though explicitly parsing your input to a number would be a good idea, JS will do what it can, but it can't read your mind) can you give us an example of an input that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, but, with parseInt($("#new").val()) if I write a number (f.e 452) into the input, alert shows NaN.

Comment: In that case, your `#new` is not just returning 452, as that would be parsed correctly. Take a look at what value you're getting in the `sqmeter` variable. (This is why a reproducing example of the problem is very important for debugging questions, if you could add one then it would be significantly easier to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From input you get string. Cast your string to int and execute further actions.

```js
function szamolo(){

    var sqmeter = $("#new").val();
    sqmeter = parseInt(sqmeter) || 0; // Use sqmeter value or 0 if it's empty

    //#new is my input box id

    var eredmeny = ((sqmeter *0.8)/1.65);

    alert(eredmeny);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="new"/><button onClick="szamolo()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was the problem... :D I alway refered to wrong ID! parseInt was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sqmeter variable needs integer value so need to caste after getting like following:

```
function szamolo(){

    var sqmeter = parseInt($("#new").val());

    //#new is my input box id

    var eredmeny = ((sqmeter *0.8)/1.65);

    alert(eredmeny);

}
```